# ошибка Callback-a для событий загрузчика

Tags: android

В активити реализую загрузчик. В методе getLoaderManager().initLoader() this подчеркнуто красным и студия предлагает заменить его на (android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks) this. при этом во фрагменте аналогичный код, но с другой выборкой по столбцам в загрузчике и все работает. В чем может быть ошибка и почему так происходит? Насколько я понимаю заменить как предлагает студия будет неверным?

```
public class ReadActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
public static final String EXTRA_POEM_ID = "poem_id";
TextView tv_Title;
TextView tv_Poem;
TextView tv_Years;
ImageView iv_heart;
private long poemId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.read);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tv_Title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
    tv_Poem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_poem);
    tv_Years = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_years);
    iv_heart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_heart);

    poemId = getIntent().getLongExtra(EXTRA_POEM_ID, -1);
    if (poemId == -1) {
        finish();
    }


    getLoaderManager().initLoader(
            0, // Идентификатор загрузчика
            null, // Аргументы
            this // Callback для событий загрузчика
    );

}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(
            this,  // Контекст
            ContentUris.withAppendedId(PoemsContract.Poems.URI, poemId), // URI
            PoemsContract.Poems.SINGLE_PROJECTION, // Столбцы
            null, // Параметры выборки
            null, // Аргументы выборки
            null // Сортировка по умолчанию
    );
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContentResolver(), PoemsContract.Poems.URI);
    displayNote(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader) {

}
```

замена this на ReadActivity.this не помогает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку [документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager) рекомендует использовать версию из библиотеки поддержки, правильно будет так:

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(
        0, // Идентификатор загрузчика
        null, // Аргументы
        this // Callback для событий загрузчика
);
```

И (или) проверьте импорты классов/интерфейсов на которые ругается студия.